# PHP PDO statement that checks for existing username

Tags: php, sql, pdo

currently working on an application and curious as to why my script is going to a blank page once I submit my form. It started occurring when I added a piece to my script that is supposed to go into my database that checks if a username exists and then echos a message if that is the case and echos a message if it isn't the case.

This is the code:

```
function validateUser() {
    global $user, $userErr, $validForm;
    $userErr = "";
    if ($user == "") {
        $userErr = "nothing entered";
        $validForm = false;
    }
else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+(([\'\,\.\- ][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-
Z]*)*$/",$user)) {
    $userErr = "invalid characters";
    $validForm = false;
}
elseif (strlen($user) > 1) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(username) AS num FROM credentials WHERE 
    username = :username");
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $user);
    $stmt->execute(array($user));
    $norows = $result->fetchColumn();
    if ($norows > 0 ) {
    $userErr = 'Username already taken';
    }
    else {
      $userErr='User added';
    }
  }
}
```

The bit that is giving me trouble is the last elseif statement... for some reason it hasn't been doing what it's supposed to do. I've looked at many different sources and I've tried implementing different solutions but nothing has seemed to work. This function runs when the form is submitted just incase you are wondering. Very open to any possible solutions you may have. Because I just can't get it to work... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't Use `else if()` since you are using different comparison statements. Just replace all your `else if()` with `if()` only. Then use `$userErr` variable to check if the inputs pass all your validations.

```
function validateUser() {
    global $user, $userErr, $validForm;
    $userErr = "";
    if ($user == "") {
        $userErr = "nothing entered";
        $validForm = false;
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+(([\'\,\.\- ][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$/",$user)) {
        $userErr = "invalid characters";
        $validForm = false;
    }
    if (strlen($user) > 1) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(username) AS num FROM credentials WHERE 
        username = :username");
        $stmt->bindValue(':username', $user);
        $stmt->execute(array($user));
        $norows = $result->fetchColumn();
        if ($norows > 0 ) {
            $userErr = 'Username already taken';
        }
    }
    if($userErr == "") {
        $userErr='User added';
    }
}
```

Comment: changed it... here is the link to the site I put up... http://mujomusic.net/WDV341/PHP-FInal/fix.php simply click the register button and you'll see that it redirects to a blank page...

Comment: replace this line: $norows = $result->fetchColumn(); with $norows = $stmt->fetchColumn();

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in /home/www/mujomusic.net/WDV341/PHP-FInal/fix.php on line 94 this is the error...

Comment: have you used the fetchColumn() function or just fetch() ?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: conn in /home/www/mujomusic.net/WDV341/PHP-FInal/user-registration.php on line 56

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /home/www/mujomusic.net/WDV341/PHP-FInal/user-registration.php on line 56 I am getting these errors now

Comment: Updated link http://mujomusic.net/WDV341/PHP-FInal/user-registration.php

Comment: You're getting that error because you haven't setup your database connection yet. put your connection script before line 56.

Comment: Try to pass the $conn on your validateUser($conn). Do that on the function itself and to the one who's calling this function.

Comment: Can you post a code example, I'm really new to PHP so it's hard understanding some things...

Comment: $conn = your connection string here.. 

function validateUser($conn){
 Your scripts here...
}

$checker = validateUser($conn);

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: servername in /home/www/mujomusic.net/WDV341/PHP-FInal/user-registration.php on line 56

Notice: Undefined variable: databasename in /home/www/mujomusic.net/WDV341/PHP-FInal/user-registration.php on line 56

Notice: Undefined variable: username in /home/www/mujomusic.net/WDV341/PHP-FInal/user-registration.php on line 56

Notice: Undefined variable: password in /home/www/mujomusic.net/WDV341/PHP-FInal/user-registration.php on line 56

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in /home/www/mujomusic.net/WDV341/PHP-FInal/user-registration.php:56 Stack trace: #0 /home/www/mujomusic.net/WDV341/PHP-FInal/user-registration.php(56): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=;dbn...', NULL, NULL) #1 /home/www/mujomusic.net/WDV341/PHP-FInal/user-registration.php(99): validateUser() #2 {main} thrown in /home/www/mujomusic.net/WDV341/PHP-FInal/user-registration.php on line 56

Comment: Those error are from your database connection. Make sure you have a correct database connection string. Those errors did not show up last time because you are not callling the $conn before.

Comment: my connection is fine. Everything was ok up until I added this to my validation. So the problem lies there. No idea what it is though.